# I want to print If person is minor or major or senior citizen based on age when I entered in registration form using angular

Tags: html, angular

Here If I filled registration form I got the all employee details in one page but now I want
in that I have to print the column as is person minor or major or senior citizen category using angular.

```
<div class="bs-example">
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
              <th>Employee Name</th>
              <th>Employee EmailId</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
              <th>ACTION</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let emp of emps" class="table-primary">
          <td>{{emp.id}}</td>
          <td>{{emp.empName}}</td>
          <td>{{emp.empEmail}}</td>
          <td>{{emp.empAge}}</td>
        

         <td *ngIf="emp.empAge>18 else userloggedOut">major</td>
      
         
         <ng-template #userloggedOut>
          <td>
           minor
          </td>
        </ng-template>
        <!--<td *ngIf="emp.empAge <18 || emp.empAge=18">major</td>-->
          <td>{{emp.empSal}}</td>
          <td class="text-center"><button style="margin-left: -100px;" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" (click)="delteUser(emp.id)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The above code is print the whether minor or major but I didn't get code for senior citizen
please help the code for to print senior citizen also if I enter age above 60

Comment: You can create and use a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On of the possibilities would be to *ngIf :

```html
<td *ngIf="emp.empAge < 21">Minor</td>
<td *ngIf="emp.empAge >= 21 && emp.empAge < 70">Major</td>
<td *ngIf="emp.empAge > 70">Senior</td>
```

Comment: if I have age 21 it show the senior if I add above code

Comment: I edited my post. In my country you're major from 18yo. You just have to change 18 by 21

Comment: Iam new to angular please help me sir

Comment: @sudhach I edited my post because it's impossible to do this with NgSwitch. I apologize. You can simply use *ngIf :)

Comment: I have one more doubt can u please clarify that sir